# How to get location of Tweets with Twitter search API

Tags: geolocation, twitter

The `statuses/user_timeline` part of the Twitter API returns geolocation data as "place" along with each Tweet. The search API, on the other hand, does not return this location data (as far as I can tell). Is there a way to get location data with the search API?

Comment: It is returned in the `geo` field see here : https://dev.twitter.com/docs/api/1/get/statuses/user_timeline

Comment: Yeah, but I need it in the Search API results... not the user_timeline results. Thanks though :)

Answer (score 2):

There is a `geo` field in each result of the `search` resource (see the example in the [documentation](https://dev.twitter.com/docs/api/1/get/search)), which is a form of geolocation, but is not the exact same thing as the `place` field in the `statuses/user_timeline`.

Alternatively you can make another request using the `id` of the result through the `statuses/show/:id` resource (see [documentation](https://dev.twitter.com/docs/api/1/get/search)) which returns both the `geo` and `place` fields, but that would mean making one more request per result.

Answer (score 1):

[Matt asked this question directly to Twitter and got a response](https://dev.twitter.com/discussions/3755), and the dev who answered pointed out that the JSON format does include a 'geo' attribute.