# Is there a way to get the geospatail data of tweets?

Tags: python, web-scraping, twitter, geospatial

I am working on a project using social media data. An important part of it is to understand the spatial distribution of the social data, like tweets. I used the getoldtweet3 to scrape tweets but all of them are devioded of geo data. Just wonder if there a way to get the spatial features of tweets; or there are other tools to scrape other social media data with geospatial feature.

Comment: Does [this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/8189368/4376309) help?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all, the library you are using is not accessing the Twitter API, you probably know this already. It’s not official and it could stop working at any moment.

Secondly and more importantly for your question, there is only about a 1% use of geo pinning in the API. There’s no special way to go around this, it is up to a user to enable geo on their Tweets.

Does this answer your question?